# Can I use Hyperledger Couchdb mixed ordering?

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing a query for Hyperledger fabric couchdb.
Right now I am trying to query using mixed sorting.

My couchdb query is below:

```
{
    "selector": {
        "id": {
            "$eq": "D64CD784EEA6C82C165AA542BE9DC4B3E998CE3F90"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "create": "desc"
        },
        {
            "expire": "asc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to create mixed index below, but I always got error message : `Failed to create index. Reason: (unsupported_mixed_sort) Sorts currently only support a single direction for all fields.`

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         {"create":"desc"},
         {"expire":"asc"}
      ]
   },
   "name": "foo-json-index",
   "type": "json"
}
```

Couchdb doesn't support mixed index? If there are solution, please answer my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CouchDB issues and requests, I'd suggest to open an item against [CouchDB issue tracking](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues).

That is indeed an unpleasant limitation.  As a workaround, you could create an integer field that is inversely proportional to one of the dates, and then sort them both in the same direction.

Comment: I posted a new issue to the link you suggested to me. Until getting any answer from couchdb team developing, I will try solve it other way:)